# Compare two values and achieve verification in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  void _QrVerification() {
    if (_currentAddress == qrText) {
      print("DOGRU YAPTIM ");
    } else {
      print("HATA YAPTIM");
    }
  }
```

My problem is that ;

I am able to get current address via geolocator. Here I am trying to scan barcode which shows number 07600 for example. Current address postal code which ı get from gelocator is also 07600

I want to compare such both current address and scanned code. If both are same, page will be route to verification success page if not will give me error

How I can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be both of this is different format(like first is int and second value is String),
so,
set both in any single format,like

```
 void _QrVerification() {
    if (_currentAddress.toString() == qrText.toString()) {
      print("DOGRU YAPTIM ");
    } else {
      print("HATA YAPTIM");
    }
  }
```

and compare.